# How to setup Headers and body on REST POST method in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I need to setup  headers (Authorization) on the REST Client (Post method) in Pentaho.

I'm passing on the Authorization header as a parameter to the REST Client. Then use that variable inside the Headers field.

But I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

First step, set header on constant.

[image: first]

Second step, using header variable on rest client step

[image: rest client]

when I use postman passing the same headers, it works very well, like this

[image: postman call]

this is my ktr

[image: error json]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved my problem just changing REST CLIENT step by  HTTP POST, It works very well.

This damn step rest client just doesn't work when you need send a post request with json body.

[image: works very well]

Answer (score 0):

In the Field area you select the actual value of the parameter you are entering in the header, in the Name area you type in the actual Type of the parameter.

For example you would feed the Field area with a column in the rows before the step and in the Name area you would type Content-Type

The step would receive

Field -------------------------------------------Name

application/xml;charset=utf-8 ---------- Content-Type

EDIT: Image from Comment

[image]

EDIT:
KTR -

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transformation>
  <info>
    <name>call itau</name>
    <description/>
    <extended_description/>
    <trans_version/>
    <trans_type>Normal</trans_type>
    <directory>&#x2f;</directory>
    <parameters>
    </parameters>
    <log>
      <trans-log-table>
        <connection/>
        <schema/>
        <table/>
        <size_limit_lines/>
        <interval/>
        <timeout_days/>
        <field>
          <id>ID_BATCH</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ID_BATCH</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>TRANSNAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>TRANSNAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STATUS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STATUS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_READ</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_READ</name>
          <subject/>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_WRITTEN</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_WRITTEN</name>
          <subject/>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_UPDATED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_UPDATED</name>
          <subject/>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_INPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_INPUT</name>
          <subject/>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_OUTPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_OUTPUT</name>
          <subject/>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_REJECTED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_REJECTED</name>
          <subject/>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ERRORS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ERRORS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STARTDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STARTDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ENDDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ENDDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOGDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOGDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>DEPDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>DEPDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>REPLAYDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>REPLAYDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_FIELD</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOG_FIELD</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>EXECUTING_SERVER</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>EXECUTING_SERVER</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>EXECUTING_USER</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>EXECUTING_USER</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CLIENT</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>CLIENT</name>
        </field>
      </trans-log-table>
      <perf-log-table>
        <connection/>
        <schema/>
        <table/>
        <interval/>
        <timeout_days/>
        <field>
          <id>ID_BATCH</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ID_BATCH</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>SEQ_NR</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>SEQ_NR</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOGDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOGDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>TRANSNAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>TRANSNAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STEPNAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STEPNAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STEP_COPY</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STEP_COPY</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_READ</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_READ</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_WRITTEN</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_WRITTEN</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_UPDATED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_UPDATED</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_INPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_INPUT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_OUTPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_OUTPUT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_REJECTED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_REJECTED</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ERRORS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ERRORS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>INPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>INPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OUTPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OUTPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</name>
        </field>
      </perf-log-table>
      <channel-log-table>
        <connection/>
        <schema/>
        <table/>
        <timeout_days/>
        <field>
          <id>ID_BATCH</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ID_BATCH</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_DATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOG_DATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OBJECT_NAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OBJECT_NAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OBJECT_COPY</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OBJECT_COPY</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>FILENAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>FILENAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OBJECT_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OBJECT_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OBJECT_REVISION</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OBJECT_REVISION</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
      </channel-log-table>
      <step-log-table>
        <connection/>
        <schema/>
        <table/>
        <timeout_days/>
        <field>
          <id>ID_BATCH</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ID_BATCH</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_DATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOG_DATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>TRANSNAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>TRANSNAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STEPNAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STEPNAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STEP_COPY</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STEP_COPY</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_READ</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_READ</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_WRITTEN</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_WRITTEN</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_UPDATED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_UPDATED</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_INPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_INPUT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_OUTPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_OUTPUT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_REJECTED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_REJECTED</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ERRORS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ERRORS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_FIELD</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>LOG_FIELD</name>
        </field>
      </step-log-table>
      <metrics-log-table>
        <connection/>
        <schema/>
        <table/>
        <timeout_days/>
        <field>
          <id>ID_BATCH</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ID_BATCH</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_DATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOG_DATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>METRICS_DATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>METRICS_DATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>METRICS_CODE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>METRICS_CODE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>METRICS_DESCRIPTION</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>METRICS_DESCRIPTION</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>METRICS_SUBJECT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>METRICS_SUBJECT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>METRICS_TYPE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>METRICS_TYPE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>METRICS_VALUE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>METRICS_VALUE</name>
        </field>
      </metrics-log-table>
    </log>
    <maxdate>
      <connection/>
      <table/>
      <field/>
      <offset>0.0</offset>
      <maxdiff>0.0</maxdiff>
    </maxdate>
    <size_rowset>10000</size_rowset>
    <sleep_time_empty>50</sleep_time_empty>
    <sleep_time_full>50</sleep_time_full>
    <unique_connections>N</unique_connections>
    <feedback_shown>Y</feedback_shown>
    <feedback_size>50000</feedback_size>
    <using_thread_priorities>Y</using_thread_priorities>
    <shared_objects_file/>
    <capture_step_performance>N</capture_step_performance>
    <step_performance_capturing_delay>1000</step_performance_capturing_delay>
    <step_performance_capturing_size_limit>100</step_performance_capturing_size_limit>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
    <partitionschemas>
    </partitionschemas>
    <slaveservers>
    </slaveservers>
    <clusterschemas>
    </clusterschemas>
    <created_user>-</created_user>
    <created_date>2018&#x2f;08&#x2f;03 16&#x3a;21&#x3a;24.490</created_date>
    <modified_user>-</modified_user>
    <modified_date>2018&#x2f;08&#x2f;03 16&#x3a;21&#x3a;24.490</modified_date>
    <key_for_session_key/>
    <is_key_private>N</is_key_private>
  </info>
  <notepads>
  </notepads>
  <order>
    <hop>
      <from>Generate Rows</from>
      <to>Calculator</to>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
    </hop>
    <hop>
      <from>Calculator</from>
      <to>REST Client</to>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
    </hop>
  </order>
  <step>
    <name>Generate Rows</name>
    <type>RowGenerator</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
    <fields>
      <field>
        <name>call</name>
        <type>String</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <nullif>https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;gerador-boletos.itau.com.br&#x2f;router-gateway-app&#x2f;public&#x2f;codigo_barras&#x2f;registro</nullif>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
      </field>
      <field>
        <name>Content-Type</name>
        <type>String</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <nullif>application&#x2f;json</nullif>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
      </field>
      <field>
        <name>accept</name>
        <type>String</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <nullif>application&#x2f;vnd.itau</nullif>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
      </field>
      <field>
        <name>access_token</name>
        <type>String</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <nullif>1fe43b24da7e9b230bb987dbcca6806f</nullif>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
      </field>
      <field>
        <name>itau-chave</name>
        <type>String</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <nullif>8c90asc890asc807c89cxcas</nullif>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
      </field>
      <field>
        <name>identificador</name>
        <type>String</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <nullif>06017377000130</nullif>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
      </field>
    </fields>
    <limit>1</limit>
    <never_ending>N</never_ending>
    <interval_in_ms>5000</interval_in_ms>
    <row_time_field>now</row_time_field>
    <last_time_field>FiveSecondsAgo</last_time_field>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>64</xloc>
      <yloc>48</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Calculator</name>
    <type>Calculator</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
    <calculation>
      <field_name>call_esc</field_name>
      <calc_type>ESCAPE_HTML</calc_type>
      <field_a>call</field_a>
      <field_b/>
      <field_c/>
      <value_type>String</value_type>
      <value_length>-1</value_length>
      <value_precision>-1</value_precision>
      <remove>N</remove>
      <conversion_mask/>
      <decimal_symbol/>
      <grouping_symbol/>
      <currency_symbol/>
    </calculation>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>176</xloc>
      <yloc>48</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>REST Client</name>
    <type>Rest</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
    <applicationType>JSON</applicationType>
    <method>GET</method>
    <url/>
    <urlInField>Y</urlInField>
    <dynamicMethod>N</dynamicMethod>
    <methodFieldName/>
    <urlField>call_esc</urlField>
    <bodyField/>
    <httpLogin/>
    <httpPassword>Encrypted </httpPassword>
    <proxyHost/>
    <proxyPort/>
    <preemptive>N</preemptive>
    <trustStoreFile/>
    <trustStorePassword>Encrypted </trustStorePassword>
    <headers>
      <header>
        <field>Content-Type</field>
        <name>Content-Type</name>
        </header>
      <header>
        <field>accept</field>
        <name>accept</name>
        </header>
      <header>
        <field>access_token</field>
        <name>access_token</name>
        </header>
      <header>
        <field>itau-chave</field>
        <name>itau-chave</name>
        </header>
      <header>
        <field>identificador</field>
        <name>identificador</name>
        </header>
      </headers>
    <parameters>
      </parameters>
    <matrixParameters>
      </matrixParameters>
    <result>
      <name>result</name>
      <code/>
      <response_time/>
      <response_header/>
      </result>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>272</xloc>
      <yloc>48</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step_error_handling>
  </step_error_handling>
  <slave-step-copy-partition-distribution>
  </slave-step-copy-partition-distribution>
  <slave_transformation>N</slave_transformation>
</transformation>
```

Comment: My field I'm puting  `"accept":"application/vnd.itau","access_token":"1fe43b24da7e9b230bb987dbcca6806f","itau-chave":"9a6a013b-54df-49a5-bf99-f674761f5775","identificador":"06017377000130"}"` But It stil, doesn't working

Comment: You are trying to push in an entire JSON document in 1 cel correct ?
Try separating this into Content-Type, access_token, itau-chave, identificador, as the column names, and their respective values. I have update my answer with an image example.

Comment: now it returned mal formed url error =( , don't know what to do anymore

Comment: If i may, try using another program to emulate the REST calls before automating everything in Pentaho, i use Postman to test and build all REST/API/HTML calls before automating to pentaho.

Comment: I'm using the postman and it works very well, I'll put the call on my question.

Comment: I have added a KTR example for you to try yourself, i ran it and i got error authentication message, which is excpected from generated keys. Simply change the values in the Generate rows step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177398/discussion-between-luiz-kava-and-cristian-curti).

Comment: I think now my problem is in body json, I added my transfom in my question.